Lehmer's totient problem and composites with 3 or more distinct prime factors
Lehmer's totient problem asks whether there is any composite number $N$ such that Euler's totient function $\phi(N)$ divides $N − 1$.
It is an open question.  We do have $\phi(N) = N - 1$ if and only if $N$ is prime.

Given a fixed $N = pq$ for two distinct odd primes $p,q$ is there any composite number $M$ with three or more distinct prime factors such that $\phi(M)$ divides $\phi(N) = pq - (p+q) + 1$?

It should be easy to find a counterexample at least, if one exists.
Then we could ask, given a fixed $M = pqr$ for three distinct odd primes $p,q,r$ is there any composite number $L$ with four or more distinct prime factors such that ... etc.  But there is probably no point considering that if a counterexample to 1. exists.
Edit:  Question 1. is false.  A counterexample is $N = 61\cdot89 = 5429$, $\phi(N) = 5280$, $M = 5\cdot 7\cdot 11 = 385$ and we have $\phi(M) | \phi(N)$.
Edit2:  I'm making a final edit because I think there's an inkling of a good idea I'm trying to get at.
We can make a table like this:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Factorization of } N & \phi(N) & \text{Morally} \\
\hline
p & p - 1 & \prod p - 1 \\
pq & pq - (p+q) + 1 & \prod p - \sum p + 1 \\
pqr & pqr - (pq + qr + pr) + (p + q + r) - 1 & \prod p - \sum_2 p + \sum p - 1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\hline
\end{array}
Lehmer's question framed in this way is asking if there is N for which $\phi(N)$ in any lower row divides the first row "morally".  I would like my question to be whether there is N for which $\phi(N)$ divides any higher row in the table "morally", not just the first - e.g. it seems to hold for distinct $p,q,r$ that there does not exist $N=pqr$ for which $\phi(N)$ divides $pqr-(p+q+r)+1$ (second row), or $\phi(N)$ divides $pqr-1$ (first row, morally Lehmer's question).

Please edit to include your efforts.  Starting with a simple search seems like a good idea.
